# SQL time slot checking

Tags: sql, database

Consider someone booked a time slot for 5:00pm to 6:30pm.
If another person is trying to book for 4:00pm to 5:30pm, booking should be made invalid selection.
So how can we check the time slot is already taken, using sql.

Comment: Please mention your database name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use below query:

```
SELECT *
FROM bookings 
WHERE '4:00pm' <= enddate
      AND '5:30pm'>= startdate;
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume the name of the table is `bookings` and time columns are `starttime` and `endtime` if you wanna check your desired end time or start time is within any pre-booked time slot or not you can run below query.

If below query returns any row then it's been taken.

```
    select * from bookings 
    where ('4:00pm' between starttime and endtime)or 
    ('5:30pm' between starttime and endtime) or
    ('4:00pm' =<starttime and '5:30pm' >=endtime)
```